# Merge excel files into two different ones

Tags: excel, matlab, merge

I want to run in Matlab a code, where for ten excel files merges them vertically into one excel file. My question is how can I merge them vertically in two different files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're not properly checking you folder. I used `pwd` for the current folder and my matlab code was running there. I also created two folders `folder1` and `folder2` and so on with `excel.xlsx`.

You need to add an if statment to get the first file and fill the initial `dataN` to concatenate everything.

Then you can use something similar to [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362527-how-can-i-combine-data-in-multiple-excel-files-an-write-the-combined-data-in-a-new-excel-file-data-s).

My excel looks like this:

[image]

Then you need to ignore the two first folder names from the struct, that will be `.` and `..` respectively

So the code looks something like this:

```matlab
path = pwd;
S = dir(path);
isdir = [S.isdir];
n_files = 5;
for k = 3:numel(S)
    if isdir(k)
        if k < (3 + n_files)
            disp(num2str(k))
            if k == 3
                F = fullfile([path '\' S(k).name '\excel.xlsx']);
                data2 = xlsread(F);
            else
                F = fullfile([path '\' S(k).name '\excel.xlsx'])
                data = xlsread(F);
                data2 = [data2;data];
            end
        else
            if k == (3 + n_files)
                F = fullfile([path '\' S(k).name '\excel.xlsx']);
                data3 = xlsread(F);
            else
                F = fullfile([path '\' S(k).name '\excel.xlsx']);
                data = xlsread(F);
                data3 = [data3;data];
            end
        end

    else
        ;
    end
end

xlswrite('file3.xlsx', data2); % Create file 3
xlswrite('file4.xlsx', data3); % Create file 3
```

EDIT: I misread the question and didn't see you wanted the first 5. You can simply add an if statment for that then. I'm updating the code for this. You could then change `n_files` to fit the quantity of files you want.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `dir(path)` for you?

Comment: I have edited the code as I had `pwd` for everything. Try to use the edited code and change path to the one in your post `D:\2019`. You should see a list of items on the directory. If I look at my `S` parameter which is a direct `dir` function I see [this](https://imgur.com/a/JJiY65T)

Comment: The problem comes on the initial definition of `data3` inside of the `if k == (3 + n_files+1)`. Please add disp(k) inside of every if to see if it goes through properly.

Comment: Hi @mathew81, I want to help to debug this but it seems rather tricky towards here, is there any channel that we can have a more direct conversation to debug it (discord, reddit chatbox, twitter, etc) so I can help you with the debug? I'll then modify my answer accordingly to what is happening to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249031/discussion-between-mathew81-and-guilherme-theis).